# How I can return and get JSON data with Drupal 7

Tags: php, json, drupal

**card.module**

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  currentRequest = $.ajax({
  timeout:0,
  cache: false,
  url: pageUrl,
  dataType: "json",
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data){
  $("#edit-field-currency-type-und-0-value").val(data.currency);

  }

});
```

**ajax request module**

```
$items['mccurr/%'] = array(
'title' => '', 
'page callback' => 'ajax_currency_type', 
'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
'page arguments' => array(1),
'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
);

function ajax_currency_type($ccode){
 drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript; utf-8');
$query = "SELECT countries_country.currency 
        FROM countries_country
        WHERE countries_country.iso2 = '".$ccode."'";
$data = db_query($query);

return  drupal_json_encod($data);
}
```

Is this way correct to return the json data else how can i get the return data back in my car.module.

Thank You

Comment: Take care of your sql injection vulnerability..

Comment: Why do you use `jQuery(document).ready`?

Comment: @jantimon: Thanx but event could be what ever. my question is what is the correct way to return this json data back to my module?

Comment: You could just use the built in AJAX features of Drupal. It works for form element changes and link clicks.

Comment: @jantimon: is this function ajax_currency_type() is correct?

Comment: No it contains a sql injection vulnerability... replace `return`  with `echo` and it will work. However this is not the Drupal way for Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your page callback function, `print` the `drupal_json_encode`'d string instead of `return`ing it.

```
print drupal_json_encode($data);
exit;
```

Note that you module has security problems that you might need to understand first.

```
<?php
$items['mccurr/%'] = array(
  'title' => '', 
  'page callback' => 'ajax_currency_type', 
  'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
);

function ajax_currency_type($ccode){
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript; utf-8');
  $query = 'SELECT currency FROM countries_country WHERE countries_country.iso2 = :code'; // doesn't matter multi lines 
  $data = db_query($query, array(':code' => $ccode)); // Parameters, baby!
  // You will probably need to fetchAllAssoc() or something to get the data in the desired format. Also try to send proper headers on empty results, etc
  print  drupal_json_encode($data);
  exit;
}
```

With this code, your module will print the json encoded string and no other HTML will be in the output. 
Note that this is no the best way to do this. See the menu router definition of `system/ajax` path and pay attention to `delivery callback` there.